# Spring Boot CSRF Filter implemented in backend, front end sends CSRF header but http 403 error thrown

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security, csrf, http-status-code-403

I have implemented csrf filter in backend and in my front end application, I can see that XSRF-TOKEN is sent, but I still get http 403 error.

```
Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'XSRF-TOKEN'.
```

I set the same header name in both my backend and frontend app as **XSRF-TOKEN** .
You can see webconfig below.

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .httpBasic()
  .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/", "/index.html").permitAll()
      .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
      .antMatchers("/favicon.ico").permitAll()
      .antMatchers("/*.html").permitAll()
      .antMatchers("/css/*.css").permitAll()
      .antMatchers("/js/*.js").permitAll()
      .antMatchers("/currency_service/currencies").permitAll()
      .antMatchers("/currency_service/currency").permitAll()
      .antMatchers("/pages/*.html").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
    .logout()
    .permitAll()
      .and()
      .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
      .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());
}

    @Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("username").password("password").roles("USER");
}

private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
      HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
      repository.setHeaderName("XSRF-TOKEN");
      repository.setSessionAttributeName("_csrf");
      return repository;
    }
```

When I check request cookies in browser, I can see that **XSRF-TOKEN** is sent to backend. 
What could be the reason for this problem?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Not a real solution, but maybe try adding an interceptor before handling the request. Then dump the header to console to see what you're really getting.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation but I have already tried, before the page /login is called, the request is rejected by the server directly. I cannot see print out the header file coming into the server.

Comment: What about switching the order of .addFilterAfter(...) and .csrf().csrfTokenRepository()? I'm referencing https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/ where it's the ordering is different.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I changed it like that 
`.and()
 .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
 .and()
 .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);`
then this time I sent the request using app Postman (chrome addon). I specially put XSRF-TOKEN saved in server into the request then I got the following error.
`{
  "timestamp": 1459886043768,
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "message": "Invalid CSRF Token 'a49e1258-1912-461e-b918-96a8b4b9fbd7' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'XSRF-TOKEN'.",
  "path": "/login"
}`
have any idea ? @mugua

Comment: I'm wondering if removing repository.setSessionAttributeName("_csrf"); would make a difference. I'd say it's not necessary if you're just using the header name.

Comment: What's your CsrfHeaderFilter code?

Comment: Here it is,
`public class CsrfHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
   @Override
   protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
       HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
       throws ServletException, IOException {
     CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
         .getName());
     if (csrf != null) {
      System.out.println("CSRF " + csrf);
      System.out.println("CSRF not null! " + csrf.toString());
       Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");`

Comment: `       String token = csrf.getToken();
      System.out.println("Token " + token);
       if (cookie==null || token!=null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
         cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
         cookie.setPath("/login");
         response.addCookie(cookie);
       }
       System.out.println("Cookie " + cookie.getValue());
     }
     filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
   }
 }`

Comment: I'm looking for differences between yours and https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/modular/src/main/java/demo/UiApplication.java, but it's mostly just coding style from what I'm seeing. Unless I'm missing something. 
Are you still using postman? The CSRF token needs to come from the application, not postman. I'm not sure how often it changes, so I can't comment on postman working with csrf

Comment: Actually normally I wasn't using POSTMAN, I started to use it for test purpose. In POSTMAN, you can set headers, parameters etc. and I set the  header XSRF-TOKEN there with the value from the server ( I can see what token server has). Anyway I am so grateful for your help, I will also check the code you showed me on github. If I find any solution etc, I will post it here.